# Passing parameters to a Verilog function

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to pass a parameter to a function and use it as a parameter (e.g. to select bits) but I don't know how to tell the function that this input is a constant.

For example, if I wanted to do this:

```
assign foo = bar[MY_PARAM:0];
```

I want to write `my_function` so that I could do this:

```
assign foo = my_function(bar, MY_PARAM);
```

In my case I need to do a little more that just select bits but not too much, and I'll want it to work for inputs of different bit widths. 
If I just wanted to select a bit I could use the function below and I'd hope for a solution of similar form but I can't work out the syntax:

```
function my_function;
  input [3:0] data, my_bit;
  begin
    my_function = data[my_bit];
  end
endfunction
```

---

As per Silicon1602's answer, the code I'd need for this would be:

```
virtual class myClass#(parameter LOCAL_PARAM);
  static function [LOCAL_PARAM:0] my_function;
    input [LOCAL_PARAM:0] data;
    begin
      my_function = data[LOCAL_PARAM:0];
    end
  endfunction
endclass
assign foo = myClass#(MY_PARAM)::my_function(bar);
```

At first I forgot about the `[LOCAL_PARAM]` part and was just getting 1-bit back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) has a section on your particular case: 13.8 Parameterized tasks and functions. It says:

> SystemVerilog provides a way to create parameterized tasks and functions, also known as parameterized subroutines. [...] The way to implement parameterized subroutines is through the use of static methods in parameterized classes (see 8.10 and 8.25).

In your case, you should declare your function like this:

```
virtual class myClass#(parameter MY_PARAM);
    static function my_function;
        input [MY_PARAM-1:0] data, my_bit;
        begin
            my_function = data[my_bit];
        end
    endfunction
endclass
```

You could then call your function like this:

```
assign my_function_output = myClass#(MY_PARAM)::my_function(data, my_bit);
```

Please note that you may declare multiple functions in your abstract class. So, if you have a whole bunch of functions which all depend on a parameter in the same way, you could all declare them in the same class.

---

Some additional information on the `virtual` and `static` keyword in the aforementioned context:

Section 8.10 of the LRM talks about `static` methods.

> A static method is subject to all the class scoping and access rules, but behaves like a regular subroutine that can be called outside the class, ***even with no class instantiation***. A static method has no access to non-static members (class properties or methods), but it can directly access static class properties or call static methods of the same class.

By using the `virtual` keyword for the class declaration, you show the compiler that this is an abstract class (see Section 8.21 in the LRM). Creating an object of a virtual class causes a compilation error. This enforces strict static usage of the method.

Comment: Is it synthesizable? Doesn't seem to be unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

Since the question was also tagged as 'verilog', a similar trick could be played in a simple verilog. You can use parameterized modules to achieve the same effect. For example:

```
module util#(
  parameter int W = 10)();

  function funct;
    input [W-1:0] inp;
    funct = inp;
  endfunction

endmodule


module top(out, in);
  parameter W = 8;

  output wire [W-1:0] out;
  input wire [W-1:0] in;  

  util#(W) u1(); // inst util module with a parameter
  assign out = u1.funct(in); // call the function

  initial #1 $finish;

endmodule
```

By default, all functions declared within a module are static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use macro expansion to achieve this.  I wanted a function that would check different test stimulus.  The simulation arrays of 'bus' signals (or multi-bit values) and this was my 'parameter'.

```
`define MY_FUNCTION(LOCAL_PARAM)                \
function my_function_``LOCAL_PARAM``;           \
  input [LOCAL_PARAM:0] data, my_bit;           \
  begin                                         \
    my_function_``LOCAL_PARAM`` = data[my_bit]; \
  end                                           \
endfunction                                     \
```

Later...

```
`MY_FUNCTION(10)
 my_function_10 (data_ten, my_bit);  // Really my_bit is size $clog of LOCAL_PARAM.
```

Like Serge's answer, this works with Verilog (2001).  Also, you can use tasks and then the entire module net is available.  The macro call is equivalent the module instantiation with a parameter.  It is basically like the elaboration phase.

Probably the module solution has more valid syntax and constructs.  However, a macro of a function can achieve a similar result for simulation and could be suitable for some synthesis cases.